# Sphere Point Picking in Cartesian cordiantes

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have a vector A(x, y, z). Now I want to rotate the vector randomly (x by $\phi$, y by $\theta$ and z by $\psi$) in the 3D plane.

I want to pick points randomly on a sphere so that they are uniformly distributed. Preferably in the Cartesian coordinate.

Comment: There are several ways to rotate one vector to another. Do you mean to say that you want to pick a random vector of length $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ with uniform distribution?

Comment: No Length will be same but I want to rotate it by random angle phi, theta, psi

Comment: So you want a random vector with the same length as the vector you started with. A random vector with the same length as $(x, y, z)$. A random vector with the length $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. You're better off picking an entirely new vector than trying to rotate the one you have, I think.

Comment: Yes...Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment...but you were right.....But do you do that without having Sphere Point Picking.

Answer (score 0):

[One solution](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/random-points/) is to pick λ ∈ [-180°, 180°) as before and then set φ = cos-1(2x - 1), where x is uniformly distributed and x ∈ [0, 1).

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.
One can try the following:

$x$ =  $\sqrt[3]{u}\sqrt{1-v^2}\cos\theta$

$y$ =  $\sqrt[3]{u}\sqrt{1-v^2}\sin\theta$

$z$ =  $\sqrt[3]{u} v$

where $u$ = $r^3$ ($r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$)

$\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$ and $v \in [-1,1]$

For further study see this link
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html